# message: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::unique()

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to validate fields in my form and using unique rule

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($q) {
   $q->whereNotNull('password');
}) ],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5', 'confirmed','min:8'],
    'password_confirmation' => ['min:8']
]);
```

getting this error :

> message: "Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::unique()",

used this namespace :

> use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

Any suggestion please, Thanks

Comment: Which version of laravel do you use? Because you tagged version 5 and 4, in both there's not such a thing like `Rule`. Rules (in syntax that you use in the example) were introduced in 5.3.

Comment: @AdrianKokot: Version is 7.30.4

Comment: @user3653474 anything in `Contract` is an `interface`. Be careful with that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used wrong namespace. Replace

```php
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```